# Unable to git-clone: "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logi"

Tags: windows, git, git-clone

Windows 10, key stored in running Pageant, GIT_SSH set to path leading to plink.exse. The commnand goes through on Linux, so I guess the problem is with Windows and SSH settings?

The line I am calling is: git clone ssh://git.*address*/srv/git/*particularRepo*

Comment: Add your full command line for clarification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+protocol+error%3A+bad+line+length+character

Comment: Start debugging with `ssh git.address` — watch for excessive text starting with "logi".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a git@ in front of the hostname like this

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/organization/repo
```

Also if it's a github repo try copying the code from the green clone or download button.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQob4.png)

Comment: Tried, the same error occured.

Comment: otherwise if it works on linux, why not use wsl?

Comment: The linux user is my colleague, on his computer, I do not have Linux installed.